# Why Getting StackOverflowError on with Big JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I'm trying to send big string values (base64 formatted photo(s)) with android-networking library(OkHttp).

```
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();

 JSONArray photosBase64JsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (String photoBase64:myPhotosBase64
            ) {
                photosBase64JsonArray.put(photoBase64);
            }

jsonObj.put("photos", photosBase64JsonArray);

  AndroidNetworking.post(serverAddress)
                    .addJSONObjectBody(jsonObj)
                    .setPriority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                    .addHeaders("myHeader", "testing")
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject()....
```

I'm getting this exception :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:203)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.string(JSONStringer.java:354)
        at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:261)
        at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:733)
        at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:701)
        at com.androidnetworking.common.ANRequest$PostRequestBuilder.addJSONObjectBody(ANRequest.java:1394)
```

How can I send very long string values?

Comment: Have you tried a different library like retrofit or android volley? As the issue seems to be coming from within the library. Perhaps other libraries will handle larger sets of data better?

Comment: Used Jackson Parser and problem solved : ) Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 1):

Used the Fast Android Networking with Jackson Parser and problem solved : )

```
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.2'

AndroidNetworking.setParserFactory(new JacksonParserFactory());
```